# I want to to fetch 100,000 records by an SQL query using MySQL XAMPP and save in an array, but it doesn't even fetch 16,000 and halt or shows

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\MapRouting\Routing.php

Yes, I can set the maximum execution time, but I want the result in less time, like in MySQL when a person clicks on a table, it gives a result, e.g. showing rows 0 - 24 (16037 total, Query took 0.0032 seconds.)

```php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "example");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "error";
}

$rows = array();
$count = 0;

for ($J=0; $J <= 3; $J++) {
    $count = $count + 4000;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $offset_var = $i - 1;
        $query = "select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET " . $offset_var;
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
}

mysqli_close($connection);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your exact requirement of this code is, but your query efficiency seems very low.

You're running too many queries that fetch only one row per query.

```
    select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET 0
    select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET 1
    select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET 2
    select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET 3
    select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET 4
    select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET 5
    ...
```

Try this and see for yourself:

```
#$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "example");
#if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
#   echo "error";
#}
$rows = array();
$count = 0;
for($J=0; $J<=3; $J++) {
    $count = $count + 10;
    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
         $offset_var = $i-1;
         $query = "select id from shipment Limit 1 OFFSET " . $offset_var;
         #$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
         #while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         #    $rows[] = $row;
         #}
         echo $query . "\n";
    }
}
#mysqli_close($connection);
#echo "<pre>";print_r($rows);echo "</pre>";
```

If you want to run a query to get 4000 results per page/query?

Then following code would do that in 26 queries

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "example");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "error";
}
$rows = array();
$page_size = 4000;
$total_records = 100000;

$count = ceil($total_records/$page_size);
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {
   $offset_var = $i * $page_size;
   $query = "select id from shipment Limit " . $page_size . " OFFSET " . $offset_var;
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $rows[] = $row;
   }
}
mysqli_close($connection);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Brother I need all the Total records 10000 or above what ever the logic is but the problem is that it take too much time and it gives me  **Out of memory (allocated 320864256) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)** it gives maximum memory but when i decrease it gives me also an error bcz in **$rows** array it contain maximum records and my output didn't reach to fetch the all 100000 records it stops after 8000 when i output during loop

Comment: If you are not intended to display all those records to your application users then you should query only the required data(data which display on a single page).As per your above example ` e.g showing rows 0 - 24 (16037 total, Query took 0.0032 seconds.)` ...
This system might query only ~650(16037/25) per query with limit of 650 records
You should run the same query again to get the next set of data by updating correct OFFSET.Anyway taking all the data into a variable(into memory) and then do whatever you want to do, will end up in asking more memory to process

Comment: yes i did but when i storing all the data into a variable by using correct offset it gives the memory exhausted error whatever memory size it gives that error

Comment: **Ok Thank you anyway for giving your precious time bcz something i got from you**

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the size of your table it sounds like you just don't have enough time to bring back 100 thousand rows.

Try increasing the execution time limit?

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Which will give it 5 minutes to execute.

Comment: Thanks brother but i want these records in less time like in my sql when one click on table it shows all records in 000.32 seconds like  **Showing rows 0 - 24 (16037 total, Query took 0.0032 seconds.**

Answer (score 1):

By default, the maximum execution time for PHP scripts is set to 30 seconds. If a script runs for longer than 30 seconds, PHP stops the script and reports an error. You can control the amount of time PHP allows scripts to run by changing the *max_execution_time* directive in your *php.ini* file.

To change the maximum execution time, use a text editor to modify the *max_execution_time* directive in your *php.ini* file. For example, to set the maximum execution time to 600 seconds (10 min), use the following setting:

```
max_execution_time = 600
```

**This modification has to be done in your *php.ini* file.**

Answer (score 0):

Change `max_execution_time` in file *php.ini* to 600 seconds.

Or you can change it in PHP as well.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```

Here `600` is time in seconds (10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

For more information, kindly visit the page *[set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)*.